# Check for isNotEqual property in ibatis with java

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I am trying to implement the `isNotEqual` property property in ibatis.
I have 2 tables where I need to check for '0':

```
 prlines (trans=0) 
 prlines_trans (transt=0)
```

So in the below code I need to apply `isNotEqual` to so that my query should only return those results `where prlines.trans<>0 or prlines_trans.transt <> 0`
depending on the below property :

```
<isEqual property="isPlanCurrent" compareValue="true" prepend="AND "> prlines .budgetyear = (select ryear from sq_ryear) </isEqual>

<isEqual property="isPlanCurrent" compareValue="false" prepend="AND "> prlines_trans.budgetyear = (select ryear from sq_ryear) and prlines_trans.lock=9 </isEqual>
```

Comment: Did the below solution solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<isNotEqual>` Binary Conditional Attribute. Below is the sample Code.

```
<isNotEqual prepend="AND" 
             property="status" 
             compareValue="N">
MARRIED = ‘FALSE'
</isNotEqual>
```

If you are facing trouble in executing your SQL work with `<>` then you can choose one of the method below.

- Use `CDATA` as below.

> ```
>  <select id="yourId" resultMap="expectedResultMap" parameterType="java.lang.String">
>             SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM TABLE1
>             WHERE COL1 =#{COL1,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
>             ORDER BY DATE DESC
>         ) TABLE2
>         WHERE ROWNUM <![CDATA[ <= 20 ]]>
>         </select>
> ```

- Use `&lt;&gt;` as below.

> `ROWNUM &gt;= 20 ROWNUM &lt;= 20`